# SELECT all columns WHERE one column is NOT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have a table with id, name, price and people arguments. I just need to select all distinct ones but id is allways different and that is complicating my goal (I'm using id just to work with dynamic pages) so **i need to select all arguments distinct except id**. I hope I had make sense. Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks so much.

For example:

```
ID | NAME | PRICE | PEOPLE
1  | beef |  9    |   2
2  | beef |  5    |   1
3  | beef |  9    |   2
4  | pork |  6    |   1 

Result:

ID | NAME | PRICE | PEOPLE
1  | beef |  9    |   2
2  | beef |  5    |   1
4  | pork |  6    |   1
```

I already solved this. Here is the query:

```
SELECT every.name, every.price, every.people, every.id 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM sometable) AS every 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT name, price, people FROM sometable) AS unique 
ON (every.name = unique.name AND every.price=unique.price AND every.people=unique.people);
```

Comment: That is unfortunately not quite a clear enough description, since `DISTINCT` applies across the whole rowset. It would help if you post a small sample of rows in the table, together with a sample of what you would want the query output to be, given that input rowset.

Comment: If you don't want to include the id exclude it from the select. If you need the id you will get multiple rows.

Comment: You can also use an aggregate like MAX(id) in the SELECT, and then GROUP BY the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two datasets (`uniq` and `all`) from the same table and join on those.  You will only be getting rows from `uniq` that are distinct.  Therefore, you can be sure that for any entry in `all` which matches all three attributes, there is only one possible id.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id, name, price, people FROM sometable) as all
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(name, people, price) FROM sometable) as uniq  ON
(all.name = uniq.name AND all.price = uniq.price AND all.people = uniq.people) ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had some problemas but I just solved that. Thanks so much.